# Remove an eventhandler in the handler itself

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, event-handling

In short: I would like to bind the result of .bind as an arguement in it's own call

```
var bound = foo.bind(this,bound);
```

because I'm not sure how else to solve my problem.

The problem:

I have an item that is dependent on an array of other items.
Once one of those items is removed I want to remove the dependent item, *and remove all the listeners placed on the dependencies*.

I'm struggling to remove the eventhandlers of the other dependencies. I'm trying to use bind, but since the handler function is the one that removes the listeners, I find that I would have to bind the result of the `bind()` call in it's own call as an argument. This does ofcourse not work.

The bind call bellow binds the unbound version of 'handler' as a parameter, and thus removeEventListener does not work as it is a different copy of the function.

The question is: can I use bind to do this and/or how can I otherwise solve this?

Im using [eventemitter3](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eventemitter3), but it should be the same for any event library.

```
setHandlers(dependentItem,dependencies)
{
    var handler = this.onDependencyRemoved;
    handler = handler.bind(this,dependentItem,dependencies,handler);//bind itself as third argument
    dependencies.forEach(dependency => {
        dependency.addEventListener("removed",handler);
    });
}
onDependencyRemoved(dependentItem,dependencies,handler)
{
     dependentItem.remove();
     dependencies.forEach(dependency => {
          dependency.removeEventListener("removed",handler);
     });
}
```

**edit:**

Complete working example to run in nodejs:

```
const EventEmitter = require('events');
//const EventEmitter = require('eventemitter3');

class MyEmitter extends EventEmitter {
    remove() {
        console.log("I'm being removed, this should happen only once");
    }
}
var dependent = new MyEmitter();
var dependencies = [new MyEmitter(),new MyEmitter()];

var handler = (e) => removeHandler(dependencies,dependent,handler);

dependencies.forEach(dependency => dependency.once('removed',handler));

var removeHandler = function(dependencies,dependent,handler) {
    //remove the dependent object because one of the dependencies was removed
    dependent.remove();
    //remove the listeners from all of the dependencies
    dependencies.forEach(dependency => {
        console.log('before removing: '+dependency.listeners('removed').length);
        dependency.removeListener('removed',handler);
        console.log('after removing: '+dependency.listeners('removed').length);
    });
}

//should remove the dependent object
dependencies[0].emit("removed");
//should not do anything anymore since the listeners are removed
dependencies[1].emit("removed");
```

Comment: Use [event delegation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1688293/402037) and add _one_ handler on a parent element.

Comment: @Andreas I'm in node.js. The items are models / ES6 class instances, not DOM items.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot do this using `bind`, but you can do this relatively easy by using a closure - either directly for the function to be bound, or in your own helper function similar to `bind`. It's as simple as

```
const handler = (e) => this.onDependencyRemoved(dependentItem, dependencies, handler, e);
```

I'm not sure however why those two functions are methods of anything; they look rather static. It *might* make sense to make them methods of the `dependentItem`, in which case the arguments and even the whole `handler` don't need to be stored in closure variables, but could be made instance properties to be initialised in the constructor.

Comment: with the closure it still doesnt work. When I remove the event listener the handler once registered does not match (`===`) with the handler used by `onDependencyRemoved`. I've edited the question with the closure setup.

Comment: @Flion I cannot reproduce, your code should work. I believe you either haven't shown your complete actual code or the problem is elsewhere. Can you make a [mcve]? I'm also curious how you could check `===` "*against the handler function once saved with addEventListener*", as `addEventListener` doesn't make its store available

Comment: yeah I just made a minimal complete example and it worked fine both with node.js native EventEmitter and the `eventEmitter3` library. I realised not all the time removeEventListener is called it removes something because the item that emitted the 'removed' event has already removed it's own because I use `once`. Tnx for the help! I will give bounty tomorrow. This was an important issue for me and I never knew a simple closure could reuse a value in its own function like you showed.

Answer (score 6):

There are better ways to solve your problem that others have mentioned. However, there is a more fundamental problem with the code:

```
var bound = foo.bind(this,bound);
```

The value of `bound` in your code, at the time of execution, is `undefined`. This is the equivalent of just calling `foo.bind(this)` which is probably not what you want.

Comment: I'm aware of that, I only wrote it to try and explain what I was trying to do.